# Opengl es draw different textures in many triangles for once, and improve behavior

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am trying to use opengl es to write a view which can scan very huge images.
So I need to attach many small piece of imagetiles on single view. I have tried to draw every tile individually, but the behavior is very bad. The screen flashes because I clear all bit buffer before I draw a new frame and then add tiles one by one.
I searched to find that I may need to use texture atlas, but considering my tiles is not so small, so attach them together may take lot of time. And I checked some books of opengl es, only tell me single texture usage. I don't know since I have vertex and indeces arrays how to tell them to use different textures seperately and call draw  method for once.
If some one had same experience and solved the problem, please share your experience with me.

Comment: code and screenshot of the result would help in understanding the issue and in providing solution

Answer (score 0):

use glTexStorage2D/3D to set the texture size & format, then use glTexSubImage2D/3D to upload each small piece, all pieces maybe finally transfer to video memory at the same time when you call draw. But you need modify vertex texcoord attributes in this way.

Comment: I found where the problem lies. I refresh the context everytime I get a new tile, so it looks flashing all the time. Now I refresh context after I complete a whole frame, everything looks fine.